# Layout of shared memory and cache coherency

Tags: c, optimization, x86, cpu-cache, micro-optimization

I have a number of processes, about 16 (but design limit is a few hundred) that communicate via shared memory. Each process has a reserved area in the shared memory where it places requests.  When a request is ready for others, it sets a per process bit "RequestReady".  Other processes are reading the RequestReady bits inside short run spin loops and take action if bits are set. This is specific to our needs and kernel semaphores are used frequently too, but the spin loops are faster for our highly specific need (tested)

I am especially interested in effects for cross socket cache coherency on x86 platforms rather than shared L2/L3 cache designs. This is not a question about affinity, I am aware of using that.

Currently, I have the "RequestReady" bit spaced out so that each process has its bit on a seperate cache line.   Logically something like

```
 struct {
    unsigned long RequestReady;
    char DataArea[5000];
 } ProcessSlots[MAX_SLOTS];
```

This means that I essentially have up to MAX_SLOTS of cachelines, being invalidated.  The advantage is that only one core will be writing to the cacheline, and other sockets will simply need to revalidate.  This means that writer will not (should not?) write stall, but readers will at some stage when they are scanning for work.  A disadvantage is that I have used a number of cachelines that might be better for something else.

An alternative layout would be

```
unsigned long RequestReady[MAX_SLOTS];
char DataArea[5000*MAX_SLOTS];
```

This means that all the RequestReady flags are together in a cacheline, so I only have one cache invalidate message, but I am worried about creating a hotspot like this, one that will be essentially shared across every socket/core. Will this degrade so that every read/write to this cacheline will be going to main memory?

The RequestReady bits are toggled often (ca. 10,000/sec)  and scanned frequently, (ca 100K to 10M/sec).  I know I will be going to main memory access speeds often, but want a layout that minimises this for such a hot area.

What is a good approach for laying out these RequestReady bits?  Is there an alternative layout I haven't considered? Does my first approach have any advantage for the writer over the second approach?

Comment: you might think about using alignas() (C11) instead of manually filling structs manually, as that might not work as expected. Regarding cache-lines, snoop-support, etc, you might have a look at the CPU-vendor's ressources; Intel actually does provide a lot of detailed information on the r HP, ARM the like (and I suppose AMD too).

Comment: Still not clear what you mean by "looking at". You are talking about busy polling? Normally one would use a semaphore or simmilar, so the process does not consume CPU time for polling. (Wonder why one would care about cache-layout but then busy-poll a flag)

Comment: @olaf yes busy polling, have clarifed that. Not worried about cpu consumption. Have read lots of intel arch docs, but arent totally confident with my choice of option 1, hence question.

Comment: So you should also worry about DRAM layout: pages, banks et. al. Otherwise. Otherwise I would not see an issue with chache layout as the polling alone costs more CPU. Btw: you did not even mention the actual architecture; that is a crucial information.